# Auctex indentation with xemacs

Tags: indentation, emacs, auctex

I'm running xemacs 21.4.22 and auctex 11.66 on a win7 PC. Althought I'm quite sure auctex is loaded (e.g. I got the LaTeX menu with some AUCTeX references). I cannot get indentification to work. Pressing TAB gives me the following message in the minibuffer:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: match-string-no-properties.
```

Same message when I try M-x fill-paragraph or any of the kind.

Note that I use to have auctex indentation working on previous xemacs and auctex versions, so I know what I'm expecting. I turned to the new version to get the preview function on top, but it looks like I have to choose between indent and preview features which is as awkward as it is frustrating.

Comment: Hello folks,

I know the question was closed due to lack of answers. BUT, the problem was very disapointing to me, and I found a solution on another forum.

http://lists.common-lisp.net/pipermail/slime-devel/2006-December/013382.html

So, just wanted to share in case it's usefull to anyone here. It worked fine for me. :-)

Cheers,

/d